# Print fixed width list sorted by column

Tags: algorithms

I have a list of varying length where items is strings of varying length. I want to print them by (a mirrored N)/order by column.

Major points being:

- Columns shall have fixed width == widest data in that column.
- It shall be as compact as possible.
- Number of columns is varying/induced by available width of canvas.
- Order of items should **not** be rearranged.
- *(Item lists printed column wise on a horizontal order disgusts me.)*

Optionally:

- Distribution should optionally favour either lower left or upper right.

I currently use this in terminal by bash, C etc. but other uses is not hard to imagine.

Result of calculations should be:

- columns
- lines
- width of each column

As, by this, one can fairly easy print the data in a fixed with column table.

**Main question**: Is there is some nifty way to do this. *(I'm inspired by [Knuth's Computer musings](http://scpd.stanford.edu/knuth/index.jsp).)*

My current approach is rather straight forward. Hard to specify the question without some gory details so here we go:

---

### Data Examples

E.g. (by index of string array):

```
0  4  8 12   or    0  4  8 12     or   0  3  6  9 12 15
1  5  9 13         1  5  9 13          1  4  7 10 13
2  6 10 14         2  6 10             2  5  8 11 14
3  7 11 15         3  7 11             

favouring lower left     favouring upper right
0  4  8 12               0  4  8 11
1  5  9 13               1  5  9 12
2  6 10                  2  6 10 13
3  7 11                  3  7
```

E.g. (by data - actual output):

```
0) Item number 00000 4) Item Number 04        8) Item Number 008   12) Item Number 00012
1) Item Number 00001 5) Item Number 5         9) Item Number 00009 13) Item Number 0013 
2) Item Number 02    6) Item Number 00000006 10) Item Number 10   
3) Item Number 003   7) Item Number 7        11) Item Number 11
```

---

### Current implementation

As of now I do this by (approximately) e.g. in bash:

1. Adding the length of each item to array `lens` and track `longest` item.
2. Add width for number + 1 for `)` + 1 for `space` to `longest` item.
3. Calculate maximum columns given that width.
4. Re-calculating width of item number (The one before `')'` in the print.) for each column.
5. Calculating actual longest width for items in each column.
6. Re-calculating:

   ```
    while `lines` > 1 ; do

         * Available width = Canvas width - total print width
         * Test:
               Find longest item in last column as if columns was increased by 1.
         * If longest_in_last_column_test < available width
                increase columns by 1.
                recalculate all column widths.
           Else
                break
           End If
    done
   ```
7. Print list.

---

### Thoughts

Cant' help but wonder if there is some way to calculate this by other means. E.g. by using matrix mathematics, - or perhaps some nice algorithm out there.

Perhaps hard in bash, but in C by pointers to structs or object related languages.

Exempli gratia:

```
struct item {
    int len;
    char *val;
}

struct item items = {{5, "Hello"}, {3, "You"}, ...}
```

Which would give a matrix of typically

```
# index:length
0:5 1:2 2:1 3:3 4:5 
5:2 6:6 7:9 8:1 9:6
```

Then by having the restraint of sum of each row being <= available width, e.g. 25, rearrange matrix.

```
longest: 5 5 9 6 => sum 25
--------------------------
         5 3 6 1 => sum 15
         5 5 9 6 => sum 25
         1 2 1   => sum  4
```

Comment: If you could summarize the crux of your question that might help? Your actual question is probably in there somewhere but there's a lot to look over here.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: Reading it over you're correct. I'll rewrite or delete.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've come up with:

```
struct Item
{
    uint prefix_length; // for the prefix numbers; e.g. "100) " would be length 5
    uint item_length;   // length of the item
    char *item;         // string contents
}

struct Column
{
    uint starting_index;
    uint num_items;
    uint max_prefix_length;
    uint max_item_length;
}

/*
```

**Initialization**

Make a list of `Item`s and initialize their `prefix_length`s based on where they are in the list and w/e other characters the prefix will have (i.e. number length + paren + buffer space).

Then make a (dynamic) list of `Column`s, the same length as the number of `Item`s, with the `starting_index` of each column set to its index in the list (so that it corresponds to an `Item`) and `num_items` set to 1. The `max_prefix_length` and `max_item_length` should be initialized to the corresponding values of the `Item` to which the `Column` is pointing.

```
Items: [ 0 ] [ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ] [ 4 ] [ 5 ] [ 6 ] [...]
         ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^
Cols:    0     1     2     3     4     5     6    ...
```

**Main Loop**

The first thing to do in the main loop would be to iterate across the `Column`s, incrementing `num_items` by 1 and incrementing `starting_index` by 0 for the first `Column`, by 1 for the second `Column`, by 2 for the third `Column`, etc.

After the first iteration this will give you:

```
Items: [ 0 ] [ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ] [ 4 ] [ 5 ] [ 6 ] [...]
         ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^     ^
Cols:    +--0--+     +--1--+     +--2--+     +--3--+  ...
```

The second iteration would get:

```
Items: [ 0 ] [ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ] [ 4 ] [ 5 ] [ 6 ] [...]
         ^           ^     ^           ^     ^
Cols:    +-----0-----+     +-----1-----+     +-----2-...
```

Note that you'll have to remove any `Column`s whose `starting_index` becomes larger than the number of items in the `Item`s list.

After incrementing these values, set the `max_prefix_length` of each `Column` to the corresponding value of the last `Item` it points to. For the `max_item_length`, sadly, you'll have to iterate over the `Item`s the `Column` spans to find the max `item_length`.

The termination condition of the main loop will be to see whether the sum of the `max_prefix_length` + `max_item_length` of all the columns (plus whatever buffer space between the columns you want) is less than the total width you have. (Don't forget the edge condition of an `Item` that has a length greater than the total width.) **EDIT:** Sadly this termination condition would require you to keep the result of the last iteration around, since the loop would only terminate *after* an invalid result was found.

If there were some way of doing a walking maximum for the items spanned by each column, that would be awesome (but sadly I can't think of one at the moment).

---

Of course, after writing all this out I see that it's basically coming at this from the opposite direction as your algorithm; maybe it'll give you some ideas though.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have looked at various ways on this. I'm not able to find a "very smart" way to do this, but I use the base from my core in my Q - as this gives the possibility to eliminate quite a few checks, take advantage of previous calculations more efficiently etc.

Comment: This does seem like the sort of problem that _someone_ would have come up with a clever solution to. Mine was only off the top of my head. I hope you do find a smart(er) way to do this!